# Pointer "this" of a class turns into null when calling a method of that class C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, this

I know that this question has been asked before but didnt see a proper solution to my problem, my problem is that when i create a pointer of a class (PAGTexture) everything is normal but then, that pointer is passed to another class as variable and in that new class (PAGRevolutionObject) i call a method from PAGTexture and then it throws an exception. Debugging i realized that it actually enter in that method but "this" pointer is null "0x00000000 ".
This is my cpp of PAGTexture:

```
#include "PAGTexture.h"

PAGTexture::PAGTexture()
{}

PAGTexture::~PAGTexture()
{
}

void PAGTexture::loadTexture(char * path_img, GLuint min_filter, GLuint mag_filter)
{
    int imgWidth, imgHeight;
    unsigned char *image;
    image = SOIL_load_image(path_img,
        &imgWidth,
        &imgHeight,
        0,
        SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    if (imgWidth == 0) {
        std::cout << "Failed to load image." << std::endl;
    }
    GLuint id_img;
    glGenTextures(1, &id_img);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id_img);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, min_filter);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, mag_filter);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, imgWidth, imgHeight,
        0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    ep = id_img;
    id_imgs.push_back(id_img);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
}

void PAGTexture::applyTexture(GLuint id, int pos)
{
    glActiveTexture(id);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id_imgs.at(pos));

}
```

It turns into a null pointer when "applyTexture" is called because it tries to get the id from id_imgs.at(pos) and this one is null.

And this is the part where i called "applyTexture":

```
GLuint t = 33984;
if (id_revol.size() != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < id_revol.size(); i++) {
        shader_used->setUniform("TexSamplerColor", i);
        textures->applyTexture(t + i, id_revol.at(i));
    }
}
```

Notice that textures is not null pointer because i can access to "applyTexture" from there.

And this is an image of what i got debugging :
[Image Debugging the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8d7K.png)

I also tried to set a data breakpoint to know which part of my code is making that pointer corrupted following this ["tutorial"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0(v=vs.90).aspx) but i cant set that breakpoint for my vs version (VS2015) .

To be honest, i think my problem is that i'm overwritting memory from another class( my proyect is pretty big ) but even so i wanted to ask to see if there is something that i'm missing.

**By the way i'm using Visual Studio 2015 in debug mode (not release).**

Thanks in advance for any answer.

EDIT1:
As requested here is where i defined PAGTexture:

```
PAGTexture *texturesPack = new PAGTexture();
texturesPack->loadTexture("Textures/check.png", GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR);
texturesPack->loadTexture("Textures/HeadSpider.png", GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR);
texturesPack->loadTexture("Textures/wood.jpg", GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR);
objeto2->drawLowerBodySpiderAndHead(texturesPack);
```

FINAL EDIT:
Thanks everybody to answer, my problem was that i was binding that pointer in a inline function and it seems that you cant do that (still dunno why), anyway i have learned some points that i think it could be important so thanks again :D

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and check that `textures` is actually not null.

Comment: You did not make your question clear. [Your code snippets cannot be compiled into a working executable, so we cannot reproduce the problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Neither code snippet actually contains the keyword `this`, for one. Still trying to figure out where exactly your problem is located...

Comment: I have just check that and you are right, textures is null but still i can enter to "applyTexture" method, does it that makes sense?

Comment: put a breakpoint in the PAGTexture destructor and see if it is being called before you try to access applyTexture; If this is the case then your instance of PAGTexture is going out of scope before you are calling the function... So put a breakpoint at the destructor and applyTexture if destructor is hit before applyTexture, the class has gone out of scope

Comment: Calling a member function through a nullptr is undefined behaviour AFAIK, "anything can happen" i.e. it can crash or appear to work, or just crash later.

Comment: Oliver Ciappara i already did that and destructor is not called.

Comment: Can you show us where you are creating the instance of PAGTexture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assumption: "textures is not null pointer because i can access to "applyTexture" from there." is wrong. `applyTexture` is not a function pointer, it's a class method.

The compiler actually converts your object notation call into:

```
PAGTexture::applyTexture(textures, t + i, id_revol.at(i));
```

passing `nullptr` doesn't bother the compiler like at all. But when entering the method, `this==nullptr` and it crashes when you access a member.

It's different with data members (would probably have crashed at once), hence your confusion.

To play it safe, you could do things like:

```
void PAGTexture::loadTexture(char * path_img, GLuint min_filter, GLuint mag_filter)
{
     assert(this!=nullptr);
```

that will crash with a failed assertion if method is called with a null pointer (note: only works if optimizations are turned off, else the compiler assumes that `this` cannot be `nullptr` when optimizing even with `-O1`)

Comment: I didnt know that thanks for the information, gonna start again to check why textures is null.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is a symptom of undefined behaviour, not something one can rely on. Most implementation also *do* crash before the call if the function is virtual (because there's no vtable to be found).

Comment: Thanks to you i finally found why i was getting that error so the correct answer is yours.

Comment: First thing a modern compiler will do is to completely remove the `assert(this != nullptr)` because the `this` pointer cannot be a null pointer in a valid program. You won't get any protection, not even in a debug build.

Comment: using g++ 6.2.1 (is that enough "modern"?) I get `File: test.cpp, Line 9

Expression: this!=nullptr
` when doing this. Seems that it works, provided you don't enable optimization flags, in which case you would be right.

Comment: I think @j6t is correct. If I compile `if (this != nullptr) { /* some code */ }`, gcc 10.3 gives this warning **warning: 'nonnull' argument 'this' compared to NULL [-Wnonnull-compare]**

Comment: not suggesting to test with `if` but with `assert`. Anyway, has to be tested with production compiler and options, as a "smart" compiler would assume `this` is nonnull and eliminate the assert all right